# How to monitor system processes using metricbeat and docker?

Tags: docker, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, metricbeat

I want to monitor my systems processes on kibana with metricbeat, and get its data such as number of Running, Sleeping, Stopped and Zombie processes.
Using metricbeat on Docker, the only processes it manages to log are the few running in the container itself, though my system is running at least 400 processes at any time!
This is result of `top`:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In7Ys.png)

here is configs/modules.d/system.yml file:

```
- module: system
  metricsets:
    - cpu             # CPU usage
    - load            # CPU load averages
    - memory          # Memory usage
    - network         # Network IO
    - process         # System processes
    - process_summary # Process summary

  enabled: true
  period: 30s
  processes: ['.*']

  system.hostfs: "/hostfs"
```

and this is docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  metricbeat:
    image: beats/metricbeat:${VERSION}
    container_name: metricbeat
    network_mode: host
    env_file: .env
    #user: root
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 300M
    volumes:
      # general
      - certs:$CERTS_DIR
      - ./configs/metricbeat.docker.yml:/usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml
      - ./configs/modules.d:/usr/share/metricbeat/modules.d
      - metricbeat-data:/usr/share/metricbeat/data

      # system module
      - /proc:/hostfs/proc:ro
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/hostfs/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
      - /:/hostfs:ro

      # docker module
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

volumes:
  certs:
    external: true
    name: elastic-stack-certs
  metricbeat-data:
    name: metricbeat-data
```

How do I manage to get metricbeat container to monitor the main processes(those in my local system and not the ones in metricbeat container)?

Comment: please add the terminal line you used to run the docker container, i.e. `docker run ...`

Comment: I use a docker-compose file that only contains metricbeat as a service and run it by calling `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: then can you please add your docker-compose file? I want to see with what arguments you're starting metricbeat

Comment: I added it to the original question!

Comment: thanks, can you adjust your config to [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/beats/7.14/deploy/docker/metricbeat.docker.yml) and give it a try?

Comment: it looks like you have followed https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/running-on-docker.html#monitoring-host, which is great. what do the Metricbeat container logs tell you?